# Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to long

Tags: java

I am getting the above error when I am trying to set a flag and returning the value of the flag.I am writing the code below:

```
public static long insertEpaymentResDtls(PortalEpaymentResVO portalEpaymentResVO) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String flag = null;
    SppPaymentRequestKiosk sppPaymentRequestKiosk = new SppPaymentRequestKiosk();
    SppUserEformData sppUserEformData = new SppUserEformData();
    sppUserEformData = genericDao.findById(SppUserEformData.class, SppUserEformDataId.class,
            new SppUserEformDataId(portalEpaymentResVO.getMtrxId(), portalEpaymentResVO.getOxitrxId(), Integer.parseInt(portalEpaymentResVO.getTrxStatus())));
    try
        {
        if (sppPaymentRequestKiosk != null)
            {
            sppPaymentRequestKiosk.setStatus(portalEpaymentResVO.getTrxStatus());
            }
        sppPaymentRequestKiosk = genericDao.save(sppPaymentRequestKiosk);
        if (sppPaymentRequestKiosk != null)
            {
            flag = "Success";
            }
        }
    catch (Exception e)
        {
        GLOGGER.error("Exceptin occured at the time of updateStatus in EformServiceImpl." + e.getMessage());
        }
    return flag;//ERROR IN THIS LINE
    }
```

This is the code fragment.Please help.

Comment: Everything you need is said - you return a `String`, but the method returns `long`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer to the question is identical to the title text

Answer (score 1):

Your method signature states it returns primitive `long`.

Since you are returning `String flag`, you must change your return type to `String`.

As in:

```
public static String insertEpaymentResDtls(etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you method return type to String, how can you decalre long return and return String flag

```
public static String insertEpaymentResDtls(PortalEpaymentResVO portalEpaymentResVO) {
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is supposed to return a long, but you're returning a String instead.
Either change the return type to String, or define numeric values for whatever you want to return (i.e. success) and declare "flag" as a long instead of String.

You can also type, say: `flag = "1"` instead of `flag = "success"`
and return `Long.parseLong(flag);`